# How install FDF package in PHP ~5.4 on Windows and Unix?

Tags: php, unix, xampp, fdf

I have problem with install FDF in XAMPP on Windows (later I need to install on unix server).

for that need:

```
1)Edit php.ini and add extention=php_fdf.dll (I dont know where download 5.4 version)
2)Copy fdftk.dll to windows/system32 and system directory (dowloaded from adobe)
3)Restart the apache server
```

I found php_fdf.dll but as I undestood it's for php 4.

How install it?
I need parse fields on PFD via PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great. Nobody.

I avoid this library and use pdftk thought command-line